# xcode 7 swift how to make container view transparent

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode7, uicontainerview, container-view

I have 5 tabs in my application. I need to add a floating button for quick action on all my tabs.

I've managed to add the floating button at the bottom, just above the tab bar using a container view. So the container is positioned at bottom right and has a view controller which holds the button.

The problem is, if I add table views to my pages, since the container view is in front, a part of table views gets hidden. How do I make the container view transparent, so the user can see and scroll properly the table view..

Comment: .hidden = true doesn't do the trick for you?

Comment: or .backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

Comment: or .alpha = 0.0

Comment: I don't see any picture in front of my mind's eye, that is why i have no real idea what you need

Comment: hidden, hides the button as well. I selected clear color for background but it still shows a white patch kinda container

Comment: sure this "white kinda patch" is part of the container view?

Comment: clear color did the job, actually I was applying that to container, when I did that for view container to which the container was connected, it worked. Thanks

Comment: okay awesome. glad to help. i have set it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `yourContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`

Swift 3: `yourContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to decrease the value of alpha from the attribute inspector . 1 signifies max value (default value too) and 0 means complete transparent.